# how to set the events layout of the event in a calendar?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my web application, I customed an ASP.NETcClendar to display events link in it. I do it by creating `DayRender` event.

My code is something like this:

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder strEvents = new StringBuilder();
    strEvents.Append("<br /><a href=\"#\">");
    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime("2/15/2012");
    if (dt.Equals(e.Day.Date))
    {
        strEvents.Append("bingo</a>");
        e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(strEvents.ToString()));
    }
}
```

But I found there is a problem that, the layout is very ugly, I want it have enough space to show the link if exists, so it won't push the date up. Any idea?

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid that a simple ASP.NET Calendar is overwhelmed with your requirement. Where do you want to show all that text if there are multiple events on one day? I would suggest to indicate an event in a less conspicuous way(e.g. with `e.Cell.CssClass`) and only show more infos when the user selects that day.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you try this..?

```
if (dt.Equals(e.Day.Date))
{
  strEvents.Append("bingo</a>");
  e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>" + strEvents.ToString()));
  //for example what if the event were holiday it would be 
  //e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>Holiday")); does this make sense
}
```

this link maybe helpful as well as to giving you some additional ideas on how to use the control 
[The Calendar Control and the DayRender Event in ASP.Net](http://odetocode.com/Articles/223.aspx)

or this MSDN Link
[Calendar.DayRender Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.dayrender%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)